# Block quote in list

Tags: support, markdown, formatting

How do I put a block quote inside an item of an enumerated list without causing it to break the list or to end the item by its ending? What I mean is:

1. Item 1
2. Item 2

> Block quote
>   Either the rest of the item gets swallowed by the quote…
>   
>   or it leaves the item!

Is it possible to avoid that, i.e. insert the quote as a middle part in the item?

Comment: Maybe related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153326/blockquotes-in-a-list-break-blockquotes-after-the-list and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113475/how-can-i-blockquote-a-numbered-list-without-resetting-the-number-to-1

Answer (score 2):

Is the following roughly want you want to achieve?

1. Item 1
2. Item 2
3. Item 3

   > stuff in blockquote

   and more stuff

Code:

```
1. Item 1

2. Item 2

3. Item 3
    > stuff in blockquote

    and more stuff
```